# Generate query string using jquery, javascript OR PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, autofill

i have a form that users can fill out and i need the users to be able to generate a pdf with their results using query string
example

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
<select name="test" id="test">
<option id="op1" value="1">1234</option>
<option id="op2" value="2">2134</option>
</select>
</form>


<a href="url.pdf?Name=[FillStringHere]"> click here</a>   
 </body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is FillStringHere supposed to be generated?

Comment: it should generate the value that the user selected

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have the form POST?

Comment: You have an anchor outside the `body` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="pdf_a">click here</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#pdf_a').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', 'url.pdf?'+$('#form').serialize());
  });
});
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/NeL5X/

Comment: could you please show me an example of how to use this,please? i'm not too good with javascript

Comment: this is perfect! i hadn't realised it in the beginnning but now i get it! thanks a lot man! i have a million uses for this..

Answer (score 1):

This will take the values opt1 and opt2 and put it in the url as opt1=x&opt2=y.

```
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#my_link").click(function(){
        opt1 = $("#opt1").val(); // Stores the value of id-opt1 in the variable opt1
        opt2 = $("#opt2").val(); // Stores the value of id-opt2 in the variable opt2
        url = "url.pdf?opt1=" + opt1 + "&opt2=" + opt2; // Takes the above variables and creates the query to send to your file.
        window.location = url;
       });
    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form">
    <select name="test" id="test">
    <option id="op1" value="1">1234</option>
    <option id="op2" value="2">2134</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    <a id="my_link"> click here</a>
    </body>
```

Comment: You have an anchor outside the `body` tag.

Comment: thanks! howd i do this if i also wanted to show the text value of some elements and the actual Value of some others on the query string?

Comment: Edited and added comments to the answer, so it shows its easier to understand. Add variables and get the values that you want and modify the url variable to reflect the other data you wanted posted to the pdf file.